# Word for the conclusion talk of a conference

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best word for the concluding talk to a scientific conference (usually held by the conference organiser)? They mostly just thank the attendees and praise their contributions before wishing them a good trip home.

The following words come to mind:

- Conclusion
- Concluding remarks
- Summary

But they sound more like the last chapter of a thesis. Is there a word specifically for that kind of talk?

Comment: @irshadjm That doen't sound idiomatic to my (non-native) ears. It also limits the talk to thanking people, when in reality there is a little bit more to it than just thanking.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the words/phrases you've given would get the point across fine, especially since the speech you're describing is such a generic "thank you and goodbye". Personally I'd probably use "closing remarks" instead, just because the 3 options you've given could imply the previous content will be referenced, but I don't think there is any particularly used name for what you're describing.

Comment: I like "closing remarks". Gets the meaning across without implying an actual summary of the stuff that happened.

Answer (score 0):

They're normally called the "the closing talk", or more simply "the last talk".

Note this isn't quite the same as "A closing speech", which you would use for a situation **other** than a conference (eg a criminal trial).

Answer (score 0):

- Parting words
- Epilogue
- Close
- Finale
- Wind-up
- Recognition
- Discussion and Conclusion (last step of the scientific method)

Comment: I was thinking of ‘‘wrap-up’’.